# Is the Cyclomatic complexity value shown by Visual studio ILCyclomatic complexity

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ndepend, cyclomatic-complexity

I have ran code analysis on my solution using Visual studio 2012 and NDepend

For a method MethodA Visual studio shows the complexity as 105 and Ndepend shows it as 12. However the ILCyclomatic complexity in NDepend is 112.
Does this mean that the complexity shown by Visual studio is ILCyclomatic complexity or is there any configuration changes needed.
Also which one do I trust :(

Comment: Yes, it is analysing the IL, not the C# source. (See the comment [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx) under "Lines of code")

Comment: @MatthewWatson. oh then that value cannot be used to determine the maintenance effort for a unit right

Comment: Yes - and you definitely notice some difficulties in code that has a big switch statement, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the NDepend Source Code Cyclomatic Complexity (CC) definition [here](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC)

See the NDepend IL CC definition [here](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#ILCC). The Visual Studio CC is roughly similar (based on IL code).

Which one to trust? The Source Code CC if available, because the IL CC (both VS and NDepend ones) are biased by popular (yet complex) code constructs including LINQ queries, enumerator, lambda expression, anonymous methods and types...

Concerning NDepend, the Source Code CC is available if at analysis time you have both PDB files and C# source code files. More info on this [here](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-analysis-inputs-explanation).

Comment: thanks for the reply. As you said when dynamic objects are dereferenced the complexity is found to shoot up in Visual studio